# Return one string on multiple lines

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to get the function get_histogram to return a string that takes a character and creates  a separate line for each integer in a list.

```
def get_histogram(list1, char):
    output = ""
    for i in list1:
        output = output + (char * i)
    return output

get_histogram([3,1,5], "*")
```

It return all on one line like this:

```
'*********'
```

I need it to get it to return like this:

```
***
*
*****
```

It needs to return as one string, I can't just print separate lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your line to

```
        output = output + (char * i) + "\n"
```

This works because `"\n"` represents a newline.

Comment: I have tried that and all this does is returns this: `***\n*\n*****\n`

Comment: @Liam87 if you do `get_histogram([3,1,5], "*")`, yes. You want to do `print get_histogram([3,1,5], "*")`. There is no way around that if it returns as a string; that's just how Python works

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
__author__ = 'Aidan'


class Do():
    def get_histogram(self, list1, char):
        output = ""
        for i in list1:
            output = output + (char * i) + '\n'
        return output
a = Do()
ab = [1, 2, 3]
re = a.get_histogram(list1=ab, char='*')
print(re)
```

Sorry, I fixed my error(LOL).